# how to ask for more permission after initial authentication in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I've a facebook app at which I've asked users to give their email, work Info etc. The users have already granted the permission to retrieve these information.

Now I want to retrieve their phone numbers also but I've not asked for it previously.

So how do I ask the already authenticated users to give access to their phone numbers?? Is their some code which I can add and next time they logged in, they are prompted to authenticate that extra info??

Answer (score 4):

You can call FB.login again but specify the permissions you want to request for this time with scope. Example below, where you are requesting publish_stream:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // user gave permission        
  } else {
    // user did not give permission
  }
}, {scope:'publish_stream'});
```

You can also use FB.ui with method set to 'permissions.request'

See [http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method:_.27permissions.request.27](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui#method%3a_.27permissions.request.27)

Answer (score 3):

You need to send in the "extra" permissions the same way you got the initial ones. When your user hits the URL it will open up the same "permissions" box on FB that they were originally present with, but only with the new requested permissions set. They'll go through the same process of accepting or declining, then they'll come back to your site.

Edit: Make sure you add the same permissions you asked for originally, or FB will remove those original ones.

Comment: It doesn't work. Or am I missing something?? I've put <fb:login-button perms="email,user_website,user_work_history,user_mobile_phone" id="fblogin">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Do you mean it's not sending the user to the Facebook site to ask for the additional permissions, or do you mean it's not adding the permissions?

Comment: The first time user has to authenticate, the facebook pop-up comes.  Now I'd added the  'user_mobile_phone' in the perms and I was expecting that the next time the user tries to log in, he would be shown a similar pop-up with asking to allow to get the phone number just like the first time. But the pop-up is not coming.

Comment: So, looking into it a bit, it looks like "user_mobile_phone" permission is temporarily disabled by FB. Try adding another just as a test to see if your implementation is working properly.

Comment: Same question: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87398
It has been a couple of months now, have the enabled it?